# Why is the string format for VLC not working for my snapshots?

Tags: debian, vlc

**EDIT:** Nevermind, I just switched to celluloid with a mpv conf for what I wanted.

I wanted the snapshots to have the `$t` prefix (video file title) but I get no prefix at all, all I get is `_2021-08-16-13h02m51s847.png`. Am I doing something wrong here?

- OS: Debian Bullseye
- Vlc version: 3.0.16
- video type: hevc encoded in mkv container.

**My prefix setting:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `$F` which is "full name and path".  More info at https://tinyurl.com/7r9vwuns which accesses the VLC wiki.

Hope this helps.

RACER

Comment: How very suspicious of you to post a tinyurl link to the VLC wiki...

Comment: What is suspicious about that?  I provided a verifiable source for the information I posted.

Comment: My answer works -- I tested it.  I am not connected to VideoLAN, itself a nonprofit organization which gives away their software so even if I wanted to shill for them there's nothing to be gained by it for me or them.  You need either to explain your accusation or delete it.

Comment: What reason did you have to use a link shorterner? The seemingly unnecessary use of tinyurl making it so I can't see what link I'll be redirected to is what I call suspicious.

Comment: I used a link shortener because the absolute URL is 84 characters long and in my experience that's long enough to break in message board postings and emails.  I've been using tinyurl for at least 15 years and you are the very first person to suggest to me there is anything suspicious about it.  Since I also posted the target of the link ("which accesses the VLC wiki") you had the option of tracking down that URL on your own if you were concerned about the tinyurl.  IMO that would have been a much better option than slinging accusations at the person who solved your problem.